# How to compare 2 files to get only lines that are not in the second file?

Tags: python

I have 2 files like these :

```
file 1 :                     file 2 :
col1    col2                 col1     col2
john    kerry                john     kerry
adam    lord                 bob      abram  
joe     hitch
```

I would like to compare those two files based on lastnames and firstnames to get only a file that does not contain the people in file 2, that is to say :

```
desired output file :

col1     col2
adam     lord
joe      hitch
```

I tried this but I don't get the right output

```
import csv

reader1=csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'r'), delimiter='\t')
reader2=csv.reader(open('file2.csv', 'r'), delimiter='\t')
writer=csv.writer(open('desired_file.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

row1 = reader1.next()
row2 = reader2.next()

if (row1[0] == row2[0]) and (row1[1] == row2[1]):
    print 'equal'
else:
    writer.writerow(row1)
    writer.writerow(row2)
```

Comment: Add all the entries in file 1 to some kind of data structure. Remove each entry in file 2 from that data structure if it's present. Then output the data structure.

Comment: I get in first column, first row : "john, kerry" only

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a set difference:

```
with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2:
    data1 = set(f1)
    lines_not_in_f2 = data1.difference(f2)
```

If the formatting of the files can be slightly different, you might need to wrap the file objects in a generator which yields tuples:

```
def people(my_file):
    for line in myfile:
        yield tuple(x.lower() for x in line.split())

with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2:
    data1 = set(people(f1))
    people_not_in_f2 = data1.difference(people(f2))
```

This has the advantage that you don't need to read the entire f2 file into memory.  It has the disadvantage that the output names are unordered (since they are stored in a set).

Comment: @defuz -- I'm pretty sure it should.  Why not?  f1 is an iterator, and set is completely happy to work with iterators... `set(iter(range(10)))`

Comment: @defuz -- This might be the last day you use `readlines()` ;-D

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need the `csv` module if the file formats are the same.
How about this solution:

```
exclude_names = frozenset(open('file2')) # make set for performance
with open('output', 'w') as f:
    for name in open('file1'):
        if name not in exclude_names:
             f.write(name)
```

Solution with `csv` reader/writer:

```
import csv

exclude_names = frozenset(csv.reader(open('file2.csv', 'r'), delimiter='\t'))    
with open('desired_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv.reader(open('file1', 'r'), delimiter='\t'):
         if row not in exclude_names:
              writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results=[i for i, j in zip(reader1, reader2) if i != j]
```

or use `set(reader1) - set(reader2)` if the order is not important.

```
myfile = open(..., 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(results)
```

Comment: I think you want `set(a) - set(b)`.  `&` will take elements from both sets.

Comment: @ magilson -- of course you are right, misread the question, and found the items that are in both, also had i==j. fixed it.

Comment: Your first example also assumes that the rows in `a` and `b` are likely to be the same, which seems like a pretty sketchy assumption if `a` is `name_list.txt` and `b` is `exclude_list.txt`.  Finally, No need for the list-comp in your first example since `zip` is completely happy with iterators.